# 500 Server Error at log out at order page in Prestashop 1.7.3.0

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I have an e-commerce with Prestashop 1.7.3.0, and I have a problem with the log out in the front-end, in any part of the site it works correctly, but in the order page (when you proceed to make the order after the cart page), when I need to log out there, the site throw a 500 Server Error.

Any solution?
Thanks in advance.

Update.
I have activated the debug option, and this is the error that shows me.

[PrestaShopException Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PqOO.png)

It is worth mentioning that I configure the site, but I do not have the necessary knowledge to modify the code.

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to activate errors to see what exactly happens?

Regards

Comment: Hello, after I post it, I activated the debug option, I updated the post, thanks.